# Form with select tag

Tags: html, forms

I have created a search box with select tag but `:` changes to `&more%3A=abc` when query is executed. I need to add `more:abc` or `more:xyz` when user choose from the select menu.

**Is there any other workaround than jQuery?**

```
<form action="test.html" id="searchform">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search here..." 
name="q"/>
<input class="submit" type="image" src="icon.png">
```

```
<select name="more:" form="searchform">
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="abc">abc</option>
<option value="xyz">xyz</option>
```

Comment: Why do you need to have the colon? When submitting without the colon, the query will look like `&more=abc`

Comment: You could name the select as `menu` and define value of option as `more:abc`. This would have query string as `?menu=more%3Aabc` and you might want to decode the values.

Comment: I wana filter results with google cse and and the refinement should be more:abc